# Proving that $f$ is Riemann integrable on [0, 2]

Tags: calculus

Consider the task

> Let $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 1 &\text{if $0 \le x \le 1$} \\
> 0 &\text{if $1 < x \le 2$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 2]$
>    and find $\int_0^2f(x)\space dx$

This is my attempt to prove it, but I am not sure if its valid:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $P$ be a partition of the interval $[0,2]$ where $P = \{0, 1 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon, 2\}$. We have that $L(f, P) = (1 - \epsilon) \cdot 1 + (1 + \epsilon) \cdot 0 + 2\cdot0 = 1 - \epsilon = U(f, P)$. Since $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = 0 < \epsilon$, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 2]$. Since $\epsilon$ is a small quantity, it follows that $\int_0^2 f(x) \space dx = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a slight mistake here.  Your partition is fine but you should have:

$$
L(f,P) = (2 - (1 + \epsilon)) \cdot 1 + (2\epsilon) \cdot 0 + (1 - \epsilon) \cdot 0
$$

$$
U(f,P) = (2 - (1 + \epsilon)) \cdot 1 + (2\epsilon) \cdot 1 + (1 - \epsilon) \cdot 0
$$

Your conclusion is:

$$
U(f,P) - L(f,P) = 2\epsilon
$$

This is sufficient to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$.  And correct, since

$$L(f,P) = 1 - \epsilon,$$

letting $\epsilon \to 0$ you get the integral is 1.

Comment: Naturally, slight blunder.

Comment: On $[1+\epsilon,2]$, in the $L(f, P)$ part, why is the $\inf$ $1$?